# How to expand dates and generate a new column that accumulates a variable between two dates in r using tydiverse?

Tags: r, date, dplyr, lubridate

I have this data set:

```
library(dplyr)
library(lubridate)

data_a <- read.csv(text = "
date,variable_x
2019-01-01,13
2019-01-02,14
2019-01-03,15
2019-01-04,13
2019-01-05,12
2019-01-06,11
2019-01-07,11
2019-01-08,11
2020-01-01,12
2020-01-02,12
2020-01-03,11
2020-01-04,13
2020-01-05,10
2020-01-06,11
2020-01-07,12
2020-01-08,10
2021-01-01,12
2021-01-02,12
2021-01-03,14
2021-01-04,14
2021-01-05,12
2021-01-06,13
2021-01-07,13
2021-01-08,11
") %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
       variable_x = as.numeric(variable_x))
```

Also, this additional dataset sets the limits of the dates I am interested in:

```
data_b <- read.csv(text = "
year,treat,start_date,end_date
year2019,treatA,2019-01-02,2019-01-05
year2020,treatA,2020-01-03,2020-01-06
year2021,treatB,2021-01-03,2021-01-08
") %>%
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         end_date = as.Date(end_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))
```

The outcome I am looking for is this:

[image]

where I first expand the days between the `start_date` and `end_date` for each combination of year and treat, and then I calculate the `cumsum` of the `variable_x`. After searching around I approximated this solution that is not working:

```
outcome <- data_b %>%
  group_by(year, treat) %>%
  mutate(id = 1:nrow(.)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  do(data.frame(id=.$id, days=seq(.$start_date,.$end_date,by="days"))) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_x = cumsum(data_a$variable_x[data_a$date %within% interval(start_date, end_date)]))
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `id = 1:nrow(.)`.
x `id` must be size 1, not 3.
ℹ The error occurred in group 1: year = "year2019", treat = "treatA".
Run `rlang::last_error()` to see where the error occurred.
```

Any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought you could merge `data_a` with an outcome that was just built with the `do.call(data.frame( ...)` that you had made. The `rowwise()` prevented the subsequent `cumsum` from succeeding, so I left it out:

```
outcome <- data_b %>%
  group_by(year, treat) %>%
  do(data.frame(year=.$year, 
                treat=.$treat, 
                days=seq(.$start_date, .$end_date, by="days"))) %>%
# here's the "merge" with `x$days` matched to `y$date`
# that will omit non-matching dates from data_a
  left_join(data_a, by=c("days" = "date")) %>%
  mutate(cum_x = cumsum(variable_x))
# decided to leave in variable _x but you could drop that col if you wanted:
   # %>%select(-variable_x)
```

```
> outcome
# A tibble: 14 × 5
# Groups:   year, treat [3]
   year     treat  days       variable_x cum_x
   <chr>    <chr>  <date>          <dbl> <dbl>
 1 year2019 treatA 2019-01-02         14    14
 2 year2019 treatA 2019-01-03         15    29
 3 year2019 treatA 2019-01-04         13    42
 4 year2019 treatA 2019-01-05         12    54
 5 year2020 treatA 2020-01-03         11    11
 6 year2020 treatA 2020-01-04         13    24
 7 year2020 treatA 2020-01-05         10    34
 8 year2020 treatA 2020-01-06         11    45
 9 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03         14    14
10 year2021 treatB 2021-01-04         14    28
11 year2021 treatB 2021-01-05         12    40
12 year2021 treatB 2021-01-06         13    53
13 year2021 treatB 2021-01-07         13    66
14 year2021 treatB 2021-01-08         11    77
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Worked great. I selected this solution because of the simplicity. Is there any chance you can elaborate about the ```.$```? What does the ```.``` mean?

Comment: The dot in `%>%` chains is the result of all the prior operations in the chain. It’s typically a data.frame/tibble.

Answer (score 1):

The [ivs](https://davisvaughan.github.io/ivs/) package can be used for this. It is a package for working with intervals of data.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(ivs)

data_a <- read.csv(text = "
date,variable_x
2019-01-01,13
2019-01-02,14
2019-01-03,15
2019-01-04,13
2019-01-05,12
2019-01-06,11
2019-01-07,11
2019-01-08,11
2020-01-01,12
2020-01-02,12
2020-01-03,11
2020-01-04,13
2020-01-05,10
2020-01-06,11
2020-01-07,12
2020-01-08,10
2021-01-01,12
2021-01-02,12
2021-01-03,14
2021-01-04,14
2021-01-05,12
2021-01-06,13
2021-01-07,13
2021-01-08,11
") %>% 
  mutate(date = as.Date(date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         variable_x = as.numeric(variable_x))

data_b <- read.csv(text = "
year,treat,start_date,end_date
year2019,treatA,2019-01-02,2019-01-05
year2020,treatA,2020-01-03,2020-01-06
year2021,treatB,2021-01-03,2021-01-08
") %>%
  mutate(start_date = as.Date(start_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"),
         end_date = as.Date(end_date, format = "%Y-%m-%d"))

# We do `+ 1L` to your end dates because ivs uses right-open intervals
data_b <- data_b %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  mutate(end_date = end_date + 1L) %>%
  mutate(range = iv(start_date, end_date), .keep = "unused")

data_b
#> # A tibble: 3 × 3
#>   year     treat                     range
#>   <chr>    <chr>                <iv<date>>
#> 1 year2019 treatA [2019-01-02, 2019-01-06)
#> 2 year2020 treatA [2020-01-03, 2020-01-07)
#> 3 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)

# Find all instances of where `date_a$date` is between the range defined
# by `data_b$range`
locs <- iv_locate_between(data_a$date, data_b$range, no_match = "drop")
locs
#>    needles haystack
#> 1        2        1
#> 2        3        1
#> 3        4        1
#> 4        5        1
#> 5       11        2
#> 6       12        2
#> 7       13        2
#> 8       14        2
#> 9       19        3
#> 10      20        3
#> 11      21        3
#> 12      22        3
#> 13      23        3
#> 14      24        3

# Use the overlap locations from above to join the two data frames
joined <- iv_align(data_a, data_b, locations = locs) %>%
  as_tibble() %>%
  unpack(c(needles, haystack))

# Group by `range` and compute the cumulative sum
joined %>%
  group_by(range) %>%
  mutate(cumsum_x = cumsum(variable_x)) %>%
  ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 14 × 6
#>    date       variable_x year     treat                     range cumsum_x
#>    <date>          <dbl> <chr>    <chr>                <iv<date>>    <dbl>
#>  1 2019-01-02         14 year2019 treatA [2019-01-02, 2019-01-06)       14
#>  2 2019-01-03         15 year2019 treatA [2019-01-02, 2019-01-06)       29
#>  3 2019-01-04         13 year2019 treatA [2019-01-02, 2019-01-06)       42
#>  4 2019-01-05         12 year2019 treatA [2019-01-02, 2019-01-06)       54
#>  5 2020-01-03         11 year2020 treatA [2020-01-03, 2020-01-07)       11
#>  6 2020-01-04         13 year2020 treatA [2020-01-03, 2020-01-07)       24
#>  7 2020-01-05         10 year2020 treatA [2020-01-03, 2020-01-07)       34
#>  8 2020-01-06         11 year2020 treatA [2020-01-03, 2020-01-07)       45
#>  9 2021-01-03         14 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       14
#> 10 2021-01-04         14 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       28
#> 11 2021-01-05         12 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       40
#> 12 2021-01-06         13 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       53
#> 13 2021-01-07         13 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       66
#> 14 2021-01-08         11 year2021 treatB [2021-01-03, 2021-01-09)       77
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a non-equi join in data.table:

```
# load library
library(data.table)

# set your tables to be data.table
setDT(data_a); setDT(data_b)

# non-equi join, cumsum by year/treat, and select columns
data_a[, d:=date][data_b, on=.(d>=start_date, d<=end_date)][
  , .(start_date=d, end_date=d.1, days=date, cumsum_x= cumsum(variable_x)), .(year,treat)]
```

Output:

```
        year  treat start_date   end_date       days cumsum_x
 1: year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-02       14
 2: year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-03       29
 3: year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-04       42
 4: year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-05       54
 5: year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-03       11
 6: year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-04       24
 7: year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-05       34
 8: year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-06       45
 9: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-03       14
10: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-04       28
11: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-05       40
12: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-06       53
13: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-07       66
14: year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-08       77
```

Another option is to use `data.table::foverlaps()`. For this, to work, you need to set the key on data_b, and (like above) add a second date variable to `data_a` (because, while the start and end can be equal to each other in foverlaps, they can't be the same column):

```
setDT(data_a);setDT(data_b)
data_a[, d:=date]
setkey(data_b, start_date, end_date)
foverlaps(
  data_a,data_b,
  by.x = c("date", "d"), by.y=c("start_date", "end_date"),
  nomatch=0)[,cumsum_x:=cumsum(variable_x), .(year, treat)][
    , `:=`(variable_x=NULL, d=NULL)][]
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a more `tidyverse` friendly solution:

create a list of dates from your `data_a` df:

```
 library(tidyverse)

 dates_ls <- mapply(seq.Date, data_b$start_date, data_b$end_date, by = 1) %>% 
   map(enframe, name = NULL) %>% 
   bind_rows(.id = "index") # index for merging later
```

... add an index to `data_b`:

```
 data_bi <- data_b %>% 
   mutate(index = row_number())
```

... merge to get in long format for all the dates inbetween date ranges:

```
data_b_merge <- merge(dates_ls, data_bi, by = "index")
```

... and finally merge back to `data_a` and calculate the `cumsum` by the groups you mentioned:

```
 data_merge <- merge(data_a, data_b_merge, by.x = "date", by.y = "value") %>%
   group_by(year, treat) %>% 
   mutate(cumsum_x = cumsum(variable_x)) %>% 
   ungroup() %>% 
   select(year, treat, start_date, end_date, days = date, cumsum_x)
```

to get:

```
 # A tibble: 14 × 6
    year     treat  start_date end_date   days       cumsum_x
    <chr>    <chr>  <date>     <date>     <date>        <dbl>
  1 year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-02       14
  2 year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-03       29
  3 year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-04       42
  4 year2019 treatA 2019-01-02 2019-01-05 2019-01-05       54
  5 year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-03       11
  6 year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-04       24
  7 year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-05       34
  8 year2020 treatA 2020-01-03 2020-01-06 2020-01-06       45
  9 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-03       14
 10 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-04       28
 11 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-05       40
 12 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-06       53
 13 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-07       66
 14 year2021 treatB 2021-01-03 2021-01-08 2021-01-08       77
```